# Calling C++ dll from .Net code is excruciatingly slow when a debugger is attached

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, interop

I am using VS 2008 to compile and debug my code. In my application, the front end is C#, the backend is C++. I access the C++ code via interop.

One thing I notice is that if I press F5, and I link in the debug version of the native code, it would take more than 20 seconds to run the native code. If I link in the release version of the native code, the time needed to run it is cut down to 7-8 seconds.

And if I don't have the VS 2008 debugger attached ( i.e., I click on the exe outside of the IDE), and I link in the release version of the C++ code, it takes only 1 second to run the C++ code.

Note that for all the testing, the input to C++ code is always always the same.

For sure, there are some overheads associated with the attachment of debugger, and debug build. But the difference in performance is just too big. Could there be anything I miss or I can tune up?

I find that this is very puzzling; C# in my experience doesn't introduce this much overhead, regardless of whether you are running with a debugger, or whether you are running in debug mode.

Comment: don't know why this happens but i've seen many times and have not found any ways around it. I assume the jit debuger between unmarshed code and marshed code is just not very well tuned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess would be that loading the debugging symbols is what's slowing you down. I've seen the exact same thing happen with purely unmanaged C++ projects that are set to automatically load the symbol files for all of the Windows system libraries. Make sure that you're not automatically loading debugging symbols:

1. In the "Tools" menu, click "Options".
2. Expand the "Debugging" category to the left, and select the "Symbols" subcategory.
3. Check the checkbox labeled "Search the above locations only when symbols are loaded manually".

[image: Check "Search the above locations only when symbols are loaded manually"]

Additionally, consider that mixed-mode debugging is extremely slow.

If you don't need the ability to step into the code in the C++ DLL, you can try turning off the "Enable unmanaged code debugging" option in your project's properties:

[image: Uncheck "Enable unmanaged code debugging"]

Comment: Or if you need to step into the C++ code but can live without stepping through the C# code (even if just for this one debugging session) then you could set the C++ DLL project to be the startup project.

Comment: @Ciaran: How is that going to work if the C++ DLL is *not* actually the startup project? That is, what if the C# project contains the startup code needed to bootstrap the application, and the DLL is just a bunch of library functions?

Comment: @Cody Gray, you can setup DLL project in way that it launches the C# executables upon debug.

Comment: @Yeen: That would take more than the 15-20 seconds of waiting you would otherwise have to deal with. And it would require modification of your source code. Doesn't really seem like a good solution to me. But yes, anything is surely possible.

Comment: @Cody: It's just as YeenFei says. The term "startup project" really just means "Which project should Visual Studio run when you start the debugger?" In the DLL project's properties, under Debugging, set Command to point to the C# application. When you start the debugger it will run the C# app, and that will load your DLL as usual. But from the debugger's point of view you're in native C++ territory, not in the managed code world, and that's why you'll get normal native debugging performance.

Comment: This doesn't explain the big difference between Release and Debug build.  But is otherwise the usual reason for a slow debugger start.