# Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 7: Slow DLL calls from C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Due to the easier GUI development, I decided to write a `C#` application and using a `C++ DLL` containing some code from another project, instead of doing it completely in `C++`.
The `DLL` function is imported like this:

```
[DllImport("my_dll.dll", EntryPoint = "dll_function", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

The function has some parameters:

```
public static extern UInt16 dll_function(byte param1, UInt16 param2, byte param3, byte param4, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)] Byte[] param5);
```

It shall be called every `10ms`. I'm using a Multimedia timer for this.

A Stopwatch in `C#` tells me that the runtime of the `DLL` call is about 10..15ms.
Of course this kills my application, because there's no time left for all the other stuff.

But a Stopwatch in C++ tells me that the runtime of the called function is 1 ms (using `ctime` and `clock()` function with `CLOCKS_PER_SEC = 1000`)

It seems that the "overhead" of the DLL call consumes quite a lot time.
I have considered what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929616/calling-c-dll-from-net-code-is-excruciatingly-slow-when-a-debugger-is-attache) (Disable unmanaged code debugging, disable symbols loading), but it didn't help.
Building speed optimized "Release" versions has also no effect.

Is there anything else I can do or do I have to live with that issue?

Comment: Vanilla p/invokes have very little overhead, the cost comes from any required marshaling which depends on the actual data you pass to the dll ..   Your bench-marking is conducted in release mode?

Comment: "It seems that the "overhead" of the DLL call consumes quite a lot time" -- what brought you to that conclusion?  "I have considered what is described here" -- bring the substantive content into your question as a quote.  We're not going to go looking at a link; your question should stand on its own.

Comment: @Alex K.: There is indeed some marshaling. Is the array returned as param5 the critical thing? But even if I comment all write operations on this, the runtime does not improve - if this should matter at all...? And yes, benchmarking was in release mode.

Comment: If you tested in release, what has ``Visual Studio 2015`` to do with it?

Comment: @roy.ap: Edited. What brought me to my conclusion should be clear: The runtime measured inside the DLL is as expected. The runtime of the function call from C# is not.

Comment: @Rand Random: Ask me!? I just tried to give as much information as I - a quite unexperienced Windows programmer - can think of being relevant. If it isn't - all the better! ;-)